# how do i make a button that sorts my list in an ascending order(java swing)?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have created a an jtable in java swing which looks like the following[image]

I have added 6 buttons and 3 of them work fine(add,update,delete). im not worried about random match button but i want "Sort By goals" button to sort out all the records entered by the highest number of goals. same goes for points. I have tried many times but i dont seem to be able to figure out.

Here is the code for my table arrays;

```
  // create JFrame and JTable
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTable table = new JTable();

    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    c.add(table);

    // create a table model and set a Column Identifiers to this model
    Object[] columns = {"Team name", "Wins", "Losses", "Goals Difference","Points","Matches played"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);

    // set the model to the table
    table.setModel(model);

    // Change A JTable Background Color, Font Size, Font Color, Row Height
    table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.setForeground(Color.black);
    Font font = new Font("", 1, 22);
    table.setFont(font);
    table.setRowHeight(30);
  //  table.setVisible(true);
```

Here is my draft for the button;

```
btnSortPoints.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            }
        });
```

Here is my delete button;

```
 btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // i = the index of the selected row
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(i >= 0){
                    // remove a row from jtable
                    model.removeRow(i);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Delete Error");
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my entire code;

```
 public class table{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            // create JFrame and JTable
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JTable table = new JTable();
    
            Container c = frame.getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            c.add(table);
    
            // create a table model and set a Column Identifiers to this model
            Object[] columns = {"Team name", "Wins", "Losses", "Goals Difference","Points","Matches played"};
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
    
            // set the model to the table
            table.setModel(model);
    
            // Change A JTable Background Color, Font Size, Font Color, Row Height
            table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            table.setForeground(Color.black);
            Font font = new Font("", 1, 22);
            table.setFont(font);
            table.setRowHeight(30);
          //  table.setVisible(true);
    
            // create JTextFields
            JTextField txtTeamName = new JTextField();
            JTextField txtWins = new JTextField();
            JTextField txtLosses = new JTextField();
            JTextField txtGD = new JTextField();
            JTextField txtPoints = new JTextField();
            JTextField txtMatches = new JTextField();
    
            JLabel lblTeamName = new JLabel("Team name");
            JLabel lblWins = new JLabel("Wins");
            JLabel lblLosses = new JLabel("Losses");
            JLabel lblGD = new JLabel("Goal difference");
            JLabel lblPoints = new JLabel("Points");
            JLabel lblMatches = new JLabel("Matches");
    
            // create JButtons
            JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
            JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
            JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
            JButton btnSortPoints = new JButton("Sort by points");
            JButton btnSortGoals = new JButton("Sort by goals");
            JButton btnRandomMatch = new JButton("Add a random data");
    
    
            txtTeamName.setBounds(1200, 230, 100, 25);
            txtWins.setBounds(1200, 260, 100, 25);
            txtLosses.setBounds(1200, 290, 100, 25);
            txtGD.setBounds(1200, 320, 100, 25);
            txtMatches.setBounds(1200,350,100,25);
            txtPoints.setBounds(1200,380,100,25);
    
            lblTeamName.setBounds(1100,230,100,25);
            lblWins.setBounds(1100,260,100,25);
            lblLosses.setBounds(1100,290,100,25);
            lblGD.setBounds(1100,320,100,25);
            lblMatches.setBounds(1100,350,100,25);
            lblPoints.setBounds(1100,380,100,25);
    
    
    
            btnAdd.setBounds(1150, 20, 200, 50);
            btnUpdate.setBounds(1150, 80, 200, 50);
            btnDelete.setBounds(1150, 140, 200, 50);
            btnSortGoals.setBounds(920,20,200,50);
            btnSortPoints.setBounds(920,80,200,50);
            btnRandomMatch.setBounds(920,140,200,50);
    
            // create JScrollPane
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
            pane.setBounds(0, 0, 880, 400);
    
            frame.setLayout(null);
    
            frame.add(pane);
    
            // add JTextFields to the jframe
            frame.add(txtTeamName);
            frame.add(txtWins);
            frame.add(txtLosses);
            frame.add(txtGD);
            frame.add(txtMatches);
            frame.add(txtPoints);
    
    
            //Adding the labels to the frame
            frame.add(lblTeamName);
            frame.add(lblWins);
            frame.add(lblLosses);
            frame.add(lblGD);
            frame.add(lblMatches);
            frame.add(lblPoints);
    
            // add JButtons to the jframe
            frame.add(btnAdd);
            frame.add(btnDelete);
            frame.add(btnUpdate);
            frame.add(btnSortGoals);
            frame.add(btnSortPoints);
            frame.add(btnRandomMatch);
    
            // create an array of objects to set the row data
            Object[] row = new Object[6];
    
            // button add row
            btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
                    row[0] = txtTeamName.getText();
                    row[1] = txtWins.getText();
                    row[2] = txtLosses.getText();
                    row[3] = txtGD.getText();
                    row[4] = txtMatches.getText();
                    row[5] = txtPoints.getText();
    
                    // add row to the model
                    model.addRow(row);
                }
            });
    
            // Event listener for button remove row
            btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
                    // i = the index of the selected row
                    int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if(i >= 0){
                        // remove a row from jtable
                        model.removeRow(i);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Delete Error");
                    }
                }
            });
    
            // get selected row data From table to textfields
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    
                    // i = the index of the selected row
                    int i = table.getSelectedRow();
    
                    txtTeamName.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
                    txtWins.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
                    txtLosses.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                    txtGD.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
                    txtMatches.setText(model.getValueAt(i,4).toString());
                    txtPoints.setText(model.getValueAt(i,5).toString());
                }
            });
    
            // button update row
            btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    
                    // i = the index of the selected row
                    int i = table.getSelectedRow();
    
                    if(i >= 0)
                    {
                        model.setValueAt(txtTeamName.getText(), i, 0);
                        model.setValueAt(txtWins.getText(), i, 1);
                        model.setValueAt(txtLosses.getText(), i, 2);
                        model.setValueAt(txtGD.getText(), i, 3);
                        model.setValueAt(txtMatches.getText(),i,4);
                        model.setValueAt(txtPoints.getText(),i,5);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Update Error");
                    }
                }
            });
    
            btnSortPoints.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    
                }
            });
    
    
                    frame.setSize(1400, 500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Did you check out the tutorial for [How to use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), especially the section on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)?

Comment: @maloomeister yes and it did not help with this particular problem.

Comment: You are trying to sort the table by the "goals" column when pressing the button, correct? If so, then the second link should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You first need to add sorting support to your JTable. Read the `Sorting and Filtering` link from the tutorial for information on how to do that.
2. Once that is done the user will be able to sort any column by clicking on the column header of the column.

Verify the sorting works by manually clicking on the columns headers.

> i want "Sort By goals" button to sort out all the records entered by the highest number of goals and points

Now that your `JTable` supports sorting you can add add an `ActionListener` to your buttons to do the specific sorting:

```
btnSortPoints.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Points column in the model is converted to the view column

        int viewColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToView(4); 

        // Set up the columns you want to sort on

        List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(viewColumn, SortOrder.ASCENDING));

        // Do the sorting

        TableRowSorter sorter = (TableRowSorter)table.getRowSorter();
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);    
    }
});
```

`

Comment: hi , I am still trying to make my table support sorter but i still haven't been able to do it

Comment: main difference between the example and mine is that there is already data on the example one . with mine you can add the data

Comment: @Alireza1999 That is not a difference. You create your model and add data to the model. Then you add the model to the table. Then you enable sorting on the table. Any changes to the data are then done by updating the model. The data will automatically be sorted.